# Performance of many to one relation in django

Tags: django

I have a website which features famous people (each person is a row in the table `People`). For each famous person I would like to list related websites. I thought about creating a table called `Websites` and define it in the models.py module as follows:

```
class Websites(models.Model):
  website_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  related_person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Then when I load a person's page I will run a wesbsites_set() query to fetch all related website.
However, won't that kind of query "cost" in load time? Isn't there a better solution to design this problem so I won't have to run a query against the `Websites` table on each person's page load? The table itself will contain many rows!

Thanks,

Meir

Answer (score 0):

that's the SQL way to do it. The foreygn key will create a key to the People's table and as such the query will rely on the table indexes to be faster. Go for it :)